# Unknown column where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I have following DQL query

```
SELECT
    ps.id,
    MAX(ps.dueDate) as due_date,
    u.firstName as first_name,
    u.lastName as last_name,
    u.email,
    IDENTITY(ps.loanApplication) as loan_application_id,
    DATE_DIFF(MAX(ps.dueDate), CURRENT_DATE()) as diff
FROM
    Loan\Entity\PaymentSchedule ps
LEFT JOIN
    ps.paymentType pt
LEFT JOIN
    ps.loanApplication la
LEFT JOIN
    la.status s
LEFT JOIN
    la.user u
WHERE
    pt.slug != :paymentSlug AND s.keyIdentifier = :status AND diff = 14
GROUP BY
    ps.loanApplication
```

Which translates to following SQL query

```
SELECT
    p0_.id AS id_0,
    MAX(p0_.due_date) AS sclr_1,
    u1_.first_name AS first_name_2,
    u1_.last_name AS last_name_3,
    u1_.email AS email_4,
    p0_.loan_application_id AS sclr_5,
    DATEDIFF(MAX(p0_.due_date), CURRENT_DATE) AS sclr_6 
FROM
    payment_schedule p0_
LEFT JOIN
    payment_type p2_ ON p0_.payment_type_id = p2_.id
LEFT JOIN
    loan_application l3_ ON p0_.loan_application_id = l3_.id
LEFT JOIN 
    loan_application_status l4_ ON l3_.loan_application_status_id = l4_.id
LEFT JOIN
    user u1_ ON l3_.user_id = u1_.id
WHERE
    p2_.slug <> ? AND l4_.key_identifier = ? AND sclr_6 = 14
GROUP BY
    p0_.loan_application_id
```

This gives me following error

```
======================================================================
 PDOException
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sclr_6' in 'where clause'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When i replace WHERE condition

```
WHERE pt.slug != :paymentSlug AND s.keyIdentifier = :status AND diff = 14
```

With

```
WHERE pt.slug != :paymentSlug AND s.keyIdentifier = :status
```

It works perfectly and displays me correct record, i also tried following WHERE condition

```
WHERE pt.slug != :paymentSlug AND s.keyIdentifier = :status AND DATE_DIFF(MAX(ps.dueDate), CURRENT_DATE()) = :days_diff

WHERE pt.slug != :paymentSlug AND s.keyIdentifier = :status HAVING (DATE_DIFF(MAX(ps.dueDate), CURRENT_DATE())) = :days_diff
```

Above WHERE does not work as well, what am i missing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Move the DATE_DIFF() down to the where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the alias in your WHERE clause you need a `sub-select`.

```
select *
from 
(SELECT
    p0_.id AS id_0,
    MAX(p0_.due_date) AS sclr_1,
    u1_.first_name AS first_name_2,
    u1_.last_name AS last_name_3,
    u1_.email AS email_4,
    p0_.loan_application_id AS sclr_5,
    DATEDIFF(MAX(p0_.due_date), CURRENT_DATE) AS sclr_6 
FROM
    payment_schedule p0_
LEFT JOIN
    payment_type p2_ ON p0_.payment_type_id = p2_.id
LEFT JOIN
    loan_application l3_ ON p0_.loan_application_id = l3_.id
LEFT JOIN 
    loan_application_status l4_ ON l3_.loan_application_status_id = l4_.id
LEFT JOIN
    user u1_ ON l3_.user_id = u1_.id
) A
WHERE
    slug <> ? AND key_identifier = ? AND sclr_6 = 14
```

This is how query is logically processed

```
FROM clause
WHERE clause
SELECT clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
ORDER BY clause
```

Since `Where` comes before `Select` you cannot use `alias name` in `Where` clause

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar - Updated check now

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an alias (on the final result fields) in the `WHERE` clause; however, at least with MySQL, you may use a `HAVING` clause without needing a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you are using is the result of an aggregation.  Replace add a `having` clause so the query looks like;

```
SELECT . . .
WHERE p2_.slug <> ? AND l4_.key_identifier = ? 
GROUP BY p0_.loan_application_id
HAVING sclr_6 = 14
```

Note that `date_diff()` is not a function in MySQL.  You intend `datediff()`.